# как сделать два рабочих окна tkinter python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter

Хочу сделать при запуске программы два окна, что бы на обоих отображались фотографии, но почему то виджеты перескакивают на одно окно и получается дублирование. Библиотека `Tkinter` `python 3.6`

Мой код:

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk

class Application_left(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_widgets_left()


    def set_widgets_left(self):
        # Create widget
        self.photo_left = tk.Label(image="1.jpg")
        self.group_left = tk.Label(text="группа левый", fg="#333", font='Arial') 


        self.photo_left.pack()
        self.group_left.pack()



class Application_right(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_widgets_right()

    def set_widgets_right(self):
        # Create widget
        self.photo_right = tk.Label(image="2.jpg")
        self.group_right = tk.Label(text="группа правый", fg="#333", font='Arial 26')

        self.photo_right.pack()
        self.group_right.pack()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root_left = tk.Tk()
    root_left.title("Левый")
    root_right = tk.Tk()
    root_right.title("Правый")
    root_left.geometry("600x650")
    root_right.geometry("600x650")
    app_left = Application_left(master=root_left)
    app_right = Application_right(master=root_right)
    app_left.mainloop()
    app_right.mainloop()
```

Comment: В Tkinter не может быть два "рутовых" окна. Гуглите Toplevel окна, или подождите до вечера, я постараюсь написать ответ (если никто раньше не ответит).

Comment: @insolor Спасибо)) я немного понял как работать вот таким образом 
`root = Tk()
    root.title("hello")
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Python")
    top.mainloop()`
 Я буду очень благодарен если вы покажете, как работать с виджетами этих окон через классы

Answer (score 4):

Как уже прокомментировал [@insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814886/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-tkinter-python-3-6#comment1293787_814886) что нельзя создавать несколько `Tk` окон, для этого надо создать окно верхнего уровня `Toplevel` и в нем уже добавлять нужную для вас информацию исправленный ваш пример кода ниже.

```
import tkinter as tk


class ApplicationLeft(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main):
        super().__init__()
        self.main = main
        self.set_widgets_left()

    def set_widgets_left(self):
        # Create widget
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file='2.gif')
        self.photo_left = tk.Label(self.main, image=self.image)
        self.group_left = tk.Label(self.main, text="группа левый", fg="#333", font='Arial')

        self.photo_left.pack()
        self.group_left.pack()


class ApplicationRight(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main):
        super().__init__()
        self.main = main
        self.set_widgets_right()

    def set_widgets_right(self):
        # Create widget
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
        self.photo_right = tk.Label(self.main, image=self.img)
        self.group_right = tk.Label(self.main, text="группа правый", fg="#333", font='Arial 26')

        self.photo_right.pack()
        self.group_right.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root_left = tk.Tk()
    root_left.title("Левый")
    root_left.geometry("600x650")

    root_right = tk.Toplevel()
    root_right.title("Правый")
    root_right.geometry("600x650")

    app_left = ApplicationLeft(root_left)
    app_right = ApplicationRight(root_right)
    app_left.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Ну и как вариант использования в один класс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814886/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-tkinter-python-3-6/814921#comment1293872_814921)

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application:
    @staticmethod
    def set_widgets(root_window, text, font, img):
        tk.Label(root_window, image=img).pack()
        tk.Label(root_window, text=text, fg="#333", font=font).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Левый")
    root.geometry("600x650")

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.title("Правый")
    top.geometry("600x650")

    image_left = tk.PhotoImage(file='2.gif')
    image_right = tk.PhotoImage(file="1.gif")

    main = Application()
    main.set_widgets(root, "Группа Левый", "Arial", image_left)
    main.set_widgets(top, "Группа Правый", "Arial 26", image_right)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Можно кстати одним классом сделать, они же идентичны по сути.

Comment: @insolor да я согласен(просто для наглядности кода вопроса)